# HTML5 Video Focus for Input Devices

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a page with multiple HTML5 videos. I want to utilize keyboard and mouse events to interact with each video. In Flash, that's not a problem, because once you click on the video object, that certain video will gain focus and receive all events from any input devices, unless you click out of it. I'm still new to HTML5 videos, but I am not sure as to how to mimic this `focus` feature in HTML5 video with javascript, since `focus` doesn't exist for the video tag and you can't control a single video without it.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give an example of what kind of actions you want to happen in that interaction and what keyboard or mouse even would be attached to it?

Comment: @user156629 I don't think that should matter, because the heart of the question examines the ability of receiving focus for a particular video within a page of multiple videos, not which events attached to the object. But if you insist, using arrow-keys to scroll within the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fake `focus` for a video element by utilizing a global variable. ex:

```
    $(function(){
        var focused_vid;
        $('video').click(function(){ focused_vid = this });
        $(document).keydown(function(e){ 
            if (focused_vid){
                var skip_step = focused_vid.duration*.01;

                switch(e.which){
                    case 37: // Back arrow
                        focused_vid.currentTime -= skip_step;
                        break;

                    case 39: // Forward arrow
                        focused_vid.currentTime += skip_step;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<video id="foo">
</video>

<script>
  document.getElementById('foo').focus();
</script>
```

The focus method gives keyboard focus to an element.

Comment: I tried doing this:
`$('video').click(function(){ $(this).focus(); }).keypress(function(e){ console.log(e.which); })`

but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does if you set the tab-index to a numeric value:

```
<video tab-index='-1' />
```